# Mais de uma tabela na query - LEFT JOIN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Ajuda em SQL:

`Query`:

```
SELECT * FROM concursos 
LEFT JOIN concursos_categorias ON concursos.id = concursos_categorias.idConcurso 
LEFT JOIN categorias_concursos ON concursos_categorias.idCategoria = categorias_concursos.id 
WHERE concursos.id = 15
```

- `concursos` é minha tabela onde tem todos os meus concursos
- `categorias_concursos` é a tabela onde tem todas as categorias
- `concursos_categorias` é minha tabela onde as categorias do concurso

na tabela `concursos_categorias` tem as colunas `idConcurso` e `idCategoria`

A query ela ta me trazendo as categorias do concurso,
porem eu precisava também trazer as demais categorias, não repetindo as que tiver desse concurso.

Comment: Se você descobriu a solução, poste-a como resposta e marque-a como resposta aceita. Além de válido é incentivado.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUÇÃO**

```
SELECT * FROM categorias_concursos cat 
LEFT JOIN concursos_categorias con ON cat.id = con.idCategoria and con.idConcurso = '$id' 
LEFT JOIN concursos c ON con.idConcurso = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar group_by que assim ele elemina as colunas repetidas.